# Find out if element if element exist on page puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am looking for a way to check if an element exists on a page. If it does not exist, I want to look for an other element.

Example:

I want to find the `h1` on a page.
If it does not exist I want to look for an `h2`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read and follow the posting guidelines [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if selector exists in puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58675083/how-can-i-check-if-selector-exists-in-puppeteer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
if (await page.$(‘h1‘) !== null) {
  console.log(‘Found a h1 element‘)
}
else if (await page.$(‘h2‘) !== null) {
  console.log(‘Found a h2 element‘)
}
```

Here is the link to the solution:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1149