# how to check if an html element exists using puppeeter? is it necessary to use waitForSelector?

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I currently visit some urls, in some there is a selector and in others not, if there is a certain selector in this case `<table>` I want some action to be done.

```
    try {
        await page_table.waitForSelector('table',  { timeout: 5000 }).then((element) => {
            existData = true
        })
    } catch (err) { 
        existData = false
    }

    if(existData){
        //rest of code
    }
```

The thing is that I have to wait 5 seconds and this tag is available since I load the page. Is there any way to check if an element exists without having to wait these 5 seconds?

Note: if I put another value for the `timeout` less than 5 seconds it doesn't work and always returns false in my conditional.

Comment: Normally, you'd use `page.$` for an instantaneous yes/no check, which generally works if the element is built into the static HTML, but if it takes 5 seconds for the element to show up, then that won't work and it sounds like you're stuck waiting for 5 seconds. Can you share the page and describe what you're trying to do on it? There may be a better way to do whatever your goal is using a fundamentally different approach you may not have thought of. See [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: @ggorlen nono, when I load the page, this element exists all the time along with the page load. but the code I put is the ONLY way I get to validate if it exists or not. 

can you give me an example of something you normally use to check if something exists, without needing a timeout or something similar?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense--it's contradictory to say the element exists since the page load, but also can't be validated as existing until about 5 seconds have passed. As I mentioned, the normal approach is `page.$`, for example, `const exists = !!(await page.$("table"))` or `if (await page.$("table")) { /* element exists */ }` but this doesn't wait for the element to appear. A much more productive way to make progress here is to share the site and describe what you're trying to do on it, removing back-and-forth and guesswork.

Comment: Good, glad it worked, although this question could still be made useful for future visitors if you provided a complete, runnable [mcve] with a page and full specification. The canonical is [How can I check if selector exists in Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58675083/how-can-i-check-if-selector-exists-in-puppeteer)